# Create a default password for all new linux users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords

I know there are various ways of updating the password of a user with a script. I am looking for a way to set a default password for a new user.

/etc/default/useradd doesn't help

I don't want to set a cron that would execute a chpasswd or passwd, unless that's really the only way.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useradd does not support this, however you can just chain some commands to achieve this effect:

`useradd <USER> && echo <USER>:<PASS> | chpasswd`

Comment: Ok but that's exactly what i want to avoid.
When any user is created using useradd or adduser or anything else, I want the system to set a default password.

Comment: @momeunier: You seem to be assuming that user accounts are added by "the system" and everything else just gives requests to do so. This is incorrect. With regular local Unix accounts (/etc/passwd and /etc/shadow), the `useradd` command edits the files directly, and it's entirely up to `useradd` what password will be set. If `useradd` does not have a function to pre-set a password, then you cannot convince it to do so, except by adding such a function to useradd's source code. (`adduser` is only a script that calls `useradd`, so it would get this automatically. No guarantees about other tools.)

Comment: good point... I didn't really ask myself the right question.

Answer (score 0):

The above has some limitation, alternatively I found solution proposed here https://askubuntu.com/a/80447/1128059 is more reliable

```
usermod --password $(echo MY_NEW_PASSWORD | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) USERNAME
```